# Perl Remove outer Brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use a perl regex to remove the outer brackets in a function but I can't construct a regex that doesn't interfere with the inner brackets . Here is an example:

```
void init(){
     if(true){
     //do something
     }

}
```

into

```
void init()
     if(true){
     //do something
     }
```

is there a regex that can do this?

Comment: But why? The version with the braces is so much clearer (especially with longer function bodies). Just out of curiosity, what language is this that doesn't require braces around function definitions?

Comment: Text::Balanced `extract_bracketed` but unfortunately you have to stuff your text into a multiline string.

Comment: Maybe it's one step in a C-to-XS converter.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Python? I've heard they replaced braces with indentation. It's a matter of taste but I prefer the curlies.

Comment: @PerlDog  Yes, no curlies in Python ... but this is not Python code.

Comment: @zdim Well, we once had a really ugly script at work and a coworker asked “what language is it written in?”. We simply answered “nobody can tell!”. Perhaps _that_ was Python. ;-) (actually it was a shell script)

Comment: For arbitrary nesting you can try a recursive regex [like this](https://regex101.com/r/nU2bZ4/2).

Comment: The example is just motivational. I want to translate a domain specific description to a cpp file. Since the domain specific language is so close to C I thought that a compiler is a larger overhead than just using a simple string replace script.

Comment: But the braces are required in C++.

Comment: @bobblebubble That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write a parser for the language. Here's a simplified example using [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Marpa::R2;

my $input = << '__IN__';
void init(){
     if(true){
     //do something
     }

}
__IN__

my $dsl = << '__DSL__';

:default ::= action => concat
lexeme default = latm => 1

FuncDef ::= type name Arglist ('{') Body ('}')
Arglist ::= '(' Args ')'
Args    ::= Arg*   separator => comma
Arg     ::= type name
Body    ::= Block+
Block   ::= nonbrace
          | '{' nonbrace '}'


nonbrace ~ [^{}]*
comma    ~ ','
type     ~ 'void'
name     ~ [\w]+
space    ~ [\s]+
:discard ~ space

__DSL__

sub concat { shift; join ' ', @_ }

my $grammar = 'Marpa::R2::Scanless::G'->new({ source => \$dsl });
my $value = $grammar->parse(\$input, { semantics_package => 'main' });
print $$value;
```

The curly brackets at `FuncDef` are parenthesized, which tells Marpa to discard them.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
my $s = "void init(){ if(true){ //do something }}";
$s =~ s/^([^{]+)\{(.*)\}([^{]*)$/$1$2$3/s;
print "$s\n";
```